# Tomcat empty POST body after first request

Tags: php, tomcat

I have an absolutely weird problem: I have a service written in php where I get the user request from:

```
$input = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
```

Everything is fine but one user is unable to use the service, because `$input` is not only at first request. We spent three days trying to fix this, nothing helps. I logged everything I could and found the difference between `$_SERVER` arrays I get:

```
in case of "good" request the [HTTP_CONTENT_ENCODING] IS NOT SET
in case of request with empty body am getting [HTTP_CONTENT_ENCODING] = gzip
```

I'm really confused with all of that but maybe there is something we could change it tomcat to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

So we solved the problem. As we all suspected the problem was on tomcat side... And it solved by truning of something called `zipMode`...